# All array possibilities

Tags: php, delphi, loops, pascal

I have pascal code (programming language actually doesn't mean anything):

> box[1] := 14;
>    box[2] := 2;
>   box[3] := 4;
>    box[4] := 5;
>   box[5] := 6;
>    box[6] := 8;

I want to get all possibilities. For instance, box[1] = box[6], then box[6] = box[1]. Yes, I can write it by my hand, but I guess I can make it more clever, by loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "box[1] = box[6], then box[6] = box[1]"?

Comment: It is example. It can be also box[1] = 2; box[2] = 14; box[3] = 6; box[5] = 4 and etc. All possibilities.

Comment: By the way, this thing will have 6! ( 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 720) possibilities, maybe it will be a little bit more clear.

Comment: Do you mean you want all permutations of the numbers 14, 2, 4, 5, 6 and 8?

Comment: Then this might help: http://www.google.com/search?q=permutation+algorithm

Comment: -1 because this question is presented as a programming question and not a statistics/permutation question, and as a programming question, it is not described well enough to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken the first permutation algorithm I found in wikipedia and implemented it in Delphi (2009); I hope that is what you are looking for:

```
type
  TIntegerArray = array of Integer;

procedure Permutation(K: Integer; var A: TIntegerArray);
var
  I, J: Integer;
  Tmp: Integer;

begin
  for I:= 2 to Length(A) do begin
    J:= K mod I;
    Tmp:= A[J];
    A[J]:= A[I - 1];
    A[I - 1]:= Tmp;
    K:= K div I;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  K, I: Integer;
  A: TIntegerArray;
  S: string;

begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  for K:= 0 to 719 do begin
    A:= TIntegerArray.Create(14, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8);
    Permutation(K, A);
    S:= '';
    for I:= 0 to Length(A) - 1 do
      S:= S + Format('%3.d ', [A[I]]);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

**[I've answered you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043606/one-complex-task/2079039#2079039) already? =S**

Comment: Wow ...... I can't believe that this confusing of a question has ever came up before. (It really isn't that confusing, but wow...)

Comment: It is not what I want actually, because when one array's var changes, it has to change another one. For example when box[1] becomes box[2], box[2] also has to change to box[1]

Comment: If the results are unique you can quickly delete all the arrays that have the repeated value. I'm not sure if I'm following.

Comment: Donator, when box[2] becomes box[1] and box[1] must take box[2]'s previous value, the vocabulary word you want is **swap**. The beginning-level classes that you're taking right now are more about learning the vocabulary of the topic fields than about anything else. Without the vocabulary, you won't understand anything, and nobody will understand you, as in today's example of using *possibilities* when you really mean *permutations*.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you have set of items that can either be included (1) or excluded (0). If you count from 0 to 2^(the number of items)-1, every integer will be a set of bits indicating which items are included.

If you have 7 items, in your loop from 0 to 127 the items chosen are:

```
x0000000 (loop variable = 0, no items are chosen)
x0000001 (loop variable = 1, item [1] is chosen)
x0000010 (loop variable = 2, item [2] is chosen)
x0000011 (loop variable = 3, items [1] and [2] are chosen)
...
x1111111 (loop variable = 127, items [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7] are chosen)
```